# Не создается значок приложения, невозможно открыть после установки Apk

Tags: android, apk

UPD: на реальном устройстве (установка из файла *.apk). В эмуляторе также нет ярлыка, но там оно хотя бы запускается.

UPD2: если устанавливать на телефон через Android Studio, ярлык создается.

Манифест:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mrkrot617.calc">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".gui.CalcActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: а приложение есть в списке установленных приложений?

Comment: @Andrew Goroshko, да, есть.

Comment: а как вы получаете файл апк? какая у вас версия получается - debug или release?

Comment: @Andrew Goroshko, беру из проекта по пути */app/build/outputs/apk/debug

Comment: а вы попробуйте создать установочный файл в студии, вероятнее всего проблема в том что вы берете не тот пакет который нужно)) пусть студия вам его построит и попробуйте его установить

Comment: я пересобирал апк через Build APK(s) и брал по тому пути. Вы это имеете ввиду?

Comment: также это не решит проблему с несозданием ярлыка, мне кажется.

Comment: нет не совсем, попробуйте создать подписанное приложение - Generate Signed  APK.

Comment: а где находится созданный файл?

Comment: там выскочит окошко с предложением открыть папку с файлом, там будет папка release насколько я помню

Comment: проблема решена, спасибо! вынесите ответ, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы батенька путаете создание иконки приложения в лончере и иконку приложения в списке установленных приложений.

В некоторых лончерах/оболочках, иконка/значок приложения создается автоматически, в некоторых нужны специальные усилия чтобы его создать. В общем случае, более-менее универсальный код создания иконки для любого лончера приблизительно такой (запускать в `onCreate()` главной `Activity`):

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
private void doFirstRun() {
    if (isFirstRun(this)) { //add shortcut to app in home screen
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
            createShortcut();
        else
            createPinnedShortcut(this);
        setFirstRun(this, false);
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private void createShortcut() {
    final Intent shortcutIntent = MainActivity.getStartIntent(this.getApplicationContext());
    shortcutIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    final Intent addIntent = new Intent();
    addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcutIntent);
    addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, this.getString(R.string.my_app));
    addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE,
            Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(getApplicationContext(), R.mipmap.my_icon));
    addIntent.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
    addIntent.putExtra("duplicate", false);  //may it's already there so don't duplicate
    getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(addIntent);
}

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
private void createPinnedShortcut(Context context) {
    ShortcutManager shortcutManager = context.getSystemService(ShortcutManager.class);
    if (shortcutManager != null) {
        if (shortcutManager.isRequestPinShortcutSupported()) {
            Intent intent= MainActivity.getLaunchIntent(this);
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

            ShortcutInfo shortcut = new ShortcutInfo.Builder(context, "my_app_shortcut_id")
                    .setShortLabel(context.getString(R.string.my_app))
                    .setLongLabel(context.getString(R.string.my_app_description))
                    .setIcon(Icon.createWithResource(context, R.mipmap.my_icon))
                    .setIntent(intent)
                    .build();
            shortcutManager.requestPinShortcut(shortcut, null);
        } else
            Toast.makeText(context, "Pinned shortcuts are not supported!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

public static boolean isFirstRun(Context context) {
    SharedPreferences settings = context.getSharedPreferences(Constants.PREFERENCES_NAME, 0);
    return settings.getBoolean("firstRun", true);
}

public static void setFirstRun(Context context, boolean firstRun) {
    SharedPreferences settings = context.getSharedPreferences(Constants.PREFERENCES_NAME, 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor=settings.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("firstRun", firstRun);
    editor.apply();
}
```